# Mapnik with Postrgresql read replicas

Tags: postgresql, mapnik

This is more of a general question. We are running a GCP Cloud SQL Postgresql instance with read replicas. To distribute load, we would like to use the read replicas. We are running a nodejs service with the "mapnik" package. Is it possible to configure the "Datasource" of the "Layer" XML Object to somehow target the read replicas instead of only a single instance? I didn't found anything in the official docs though I think this scenario seems so common that is should somehow be supported.

Comment: It seems that this feature does not exist. As a simply workaround, we are now distributing the load to the read replicas by simply hard-coding the specific connection settings for each layer to target one of the read replicas.